# How to get posts with votes above a certain number? - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-votable

I'm trying to make a feed page where users can see the popular posts and the posts of whom they followed. This what I tried (but failed):

```
  @popularPosts = Post.where(cached_votes_score > '2')
```

returning an error.

```
undefined local variable or method `cached_votes_score' for #<PagesController:0x007fa2ae08f630> Did you mean? cache_store
```

Any thought on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is done:

```
Post.where('cached_votes_score > 2')
```

What you where trying to do was interpreted as trying to call a method cached_votes_score in the controller and comparing if its returned value is greater than `'2'`.

Rails doesn't have a *Railsism* to do greater than comparisons, so you do a SQL segment to accomplish it.

Comment: I think too just Post.where('cached_votes_score > 2')

Comment: You are absolutely right, specially if the 2 isn't changing as it appears to be in this example. I will update my response to help future readers.

Comment: And from 0 ->9, it's `where(' -1 < cached_votes_score < 10')` ?

Comment: Nope, that's not valid SQL. Remember know you are simply doing SQL segments inside Rails' `.where`. You want to do `'cached_votes_score >= 0 AND cached_votes_score < 10'`. Rails Active Record is a great way to get you started running queries, but its important for every Rails developer to learn the underlaying SQL as well.